# Ruby - writing a method to identify prime numbers

Tags: ruby

The below method should return `true` if an integer is a prime number and `false` if it is not. Can someone please explain to me how the placement of `true` is correct? I'm having hard time understanding how each closure (`end`) is closing each block and why placing `true` in the location it's at is correct.

This was for a lab I am completing for a course. I know the code works, but I'm unsure why.

```
def prime?(value)
  if value <= 1 || value == 0 || value == 1
    return false
  elsif
    (2..value - 1).each do |i|
      if value % i == 0
      return false
    end
  end
end
true  # <= need explanation
end
```

`prime?` should return `true` for prime integers and `false` for non-prime integers.

Comment: The `true` at the end of the method appears to be the default value which would be returned assuming all numbers smaller than the `value` checkout as _not_ being factors of that `value`.

Comment: Note that `value <= 1 || value == 0 || value == 1` is the same as `value <= 1`. Often that is written as a *guard clause*: `return false if value <= 1`. By doing so, there is no `elsif` or the associated `end`.

Comment: BTW, Ruby has a baked-in primality generator and tester. For practice this is nice; for real world, you'd use [this](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Prime.html).

Comment: Also, be careful when writing about code. Editors usually make a fuss, but for programmers it's very important to note that a sentence can, and sometimes must, start with a lowercase letter. `prime?` is not the same as `Prime?`. :)

Comment: Note that the term [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) has specific meaning in programming. Therefore, referring to `end` as a "closure" might be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reformatted this code to make the `end` closure in good indent:

```
def prime?(value)
  if value <= 1 || value == 0 || value == 1
    return false
  elsif
    (2..value - 1).each do |i|
      if value % i == 0
        return false
      end
    end
  end
  true  # <= need explanation
end
```

I guess you've familiar with the `if` part, while having a hard time with `elsif` and the ending `ture`.

Ruby methods will return its last expression's value if there is no explicit `return`. So that the last `true` will be returned **if and only if** we missed the `if` branch and went through the `elsif` branch without activate `return false`.

When will this happen?  If `value` is a prime number, of course it will fall into `elsif` branch first, then check each number less than it, see if it is divisible by any of them.

Once all trials fail,  the `elsif` branch ends, we will meet the last `true` expression.

Comment: I've moved the reformatted code into your answer. I think much of the OP's confusion is due to the misalignment (_"I'm having hard time understanding how each closure (end) is closing each block"_).

Comment: Thank you both, the explanation of the code and also the correct alignment of the code.